# Taking two inputs of two different data types in a single line in Java

Tags: java, string

In Codechef and similar sites, the inputs are taken in a single line.While taking two integer inputs in single line is no issue.But how can i can take a string input and a long input in a single line in java.Because if i enter the String first and after giving a space,I enter the the long number, won't the total line be considered as a string.**So my question is how can i take a string input and a long input in a single line in Java?**
An example -(Source-Codeforces)
5 //no of test cases
Jett 012345678  //String input and long input in a single line.
Viper 111111111
Neon 987654321
Raze 512610294
Reyna 192830492

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use a `Scanner`

Comment: Not possible multiple datatype input take in one line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1 = scanner.next();
        long input2 = scanner.nextLong();
        System.out.println("input1:" + input1);
        System.out.println("input2:" + input2);
    }
}
```

```
> javac MainApplication.java
> java MainApplication
viper 111111111
input1: viper
input2: 111111111
```

You can use next() first to capture the String datatype, then nextLong() to capture Long datatype.

Answer (score 0):

To get the string and long from one input you need to get the text and the number as a single String and then extract the number from the String. The following code shows how to get a long number from a text which are separated by a space:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1 = scanner.nextLine();
        Long a = Long.parseLong(input1.substring(input1.indexOf(' ') + 1 ));
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```